# modifying apache ports.conf via fabric script

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I am automating the deploy of a site that requires me to add a listen port to ports.conf. Right now it is ok for me to just replace the existing one but as new sites get added I would like to be able to just modify the file. I have seen examples of creating a backup of a file and writing-out the modified file in python. This seems to get me most of the way there and, python-wise, I'm sure I can figure out the rest. (making sure the change hasn't already been made, etc.) However, I'm not sure about doing this in fabric. How would I go about executing the block of python code remotely?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a line to a configuration file (and do nothing if it's already there), you can use the `append` function in `fabric.contrib.files`.

Example:

```
from fabric.contrib.files import append

append('/etc/apache2/ports.conf', 'Listen 1234', use_sudo=True)
```

See http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/contrib/files.html#fabric.contrib.files.append